# Put a div next to an image not under

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap and I have an image, and I want to have the card on the right of the image, but it is at the bottom.

I tried using `display: inline-block`, but that did not work. I looked at the other answers on the site and they did not work for me either, so please don't recommend those.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 70px; ">Crabapple Lake Parc</h1>
<img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.bb60507b5a1f567e6b6592f375bf5e8d?rik=FgkA6Taf%2fHwJsA&pid=ImgRaw&r=0" alt="Group Picture" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 50%;">
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Have Questions?</h5>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">FAQ</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @j08691 Bootstrap version 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a card next to the image using Bootstrap, you can use the grid system. In the code below, the `col-md-4` class is used to specify that the image will take up four columns out of a possible twelve, and the `col-md-8` class is used to specify that the card will take up the remaining eight columns. If you find that the card is appearing below the image, it may be because the image is too wide for the column. To fix this, you can add the `img-fluid` class to the image to ensure that it is responsive and will fit within the column.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 70px; ">Crabapple Lake Parc</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.bb60507b5a1f567e6b6592f375bf5e8d?rik=FgkA6Taf%2fHwJsA&pid=ImgRaw&r=0" class="img-fluid" alt="Group Picture">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Have Questions?</h5>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">FAQ</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your parent element you can use these styles

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

Or in Bootstrap: `d-flex` and `justify-content-between` classes:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 70px; ">Crabapple Lake Parc</h1>
    <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.bb60507b5a1f567e6b6592f375bf5e8d?rik=FgkA6Taf%2fHwJsA&pid=ImgRaw&r=0" alt="Group Picture" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 50%;">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Have Questions?</h5>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">FAQ</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### WITH TITLE IN THE TOP:

```
<h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 70px; ">Crabapple Lake Parc</h1>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.bb60507b5a1f567e6b6592f375bf5e8d?rik=FgkA6Taf%2fHwJsA&pid=ImgRaw&r=0" alt="Group Picture" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 50%;">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Have Questions?</h5>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">FAQ</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So In the `<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">` I would add `display: flex; justify-content: space-between`?

Comment: Attached the code. This will display the h1, img & the div element in row. If you want to center the content you can add the class "align-items-center" to the top div element.

Comment: This works, but I still want the Title to be above the image.

Comment: By adding the "d-flex" class (display:flex;) what you do is put all the elements horizontally inside the element. If you want the title not to be affected, this box should only have your image and the card. Answer updated, check now.

Comment: Thank you very much, just want to know if you can fix the image moving to the left, I want the image in the same place.

Comment: "justify-content-between" makes the elements be positioned as far apart as possible. If you have 3 elements, they will be positioned like this: 1----2----3. If you have two: 1----2. If you remove the class, they will be positioned to the side, starting from the left. Just remove that class.

Answer (score 0):

You *could** use [`.d-inline-block`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/display/) if it is appropriate for your layout. You need to use it on both the `img` and the `.card`.
**I'm not necessarily recommending this, but it does what you ask.*

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 70px; ">Crabapple Lake Parc</h1>
<img class="d-inline-block w-50" src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.bb60507b5a1f567e6b6592f375bf5e8d?rik=FgkA6Taf%2fHwJsA&pid=ImgRaw&r=0" alt="Group Picture">
<div class="card d-inline-block" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Have Questions?</h5>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">FAQ</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
</div>
```